# Android fragment`s inheritance with arguments

Tags: android, android-fragments

### I am knew in android and i'm not sure if i am using right approach.

I want to make small game with some levels where user make input based on what he see on the screen and if it is valid - level is passed.

I have LevelActivity which manages different fragments of levels. I wanted to make **LevelFragment** as abstruct class and then extend it with different child Fragments (Levels) such as **SimplestLevelFragment**.

All levels have some **common arguments** and i don`t know how to **pass them to superclass**?

Provided code:

***LevelFragment.java***

```
public abstract class LevelModelFragment extends Fragment {

protected boolean completed;
private int id;
private String name;
private String[] hints;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return provideFragmentView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

protected abstract View provideFragmentView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState);

public abstract boolean checkCompletion();

public abstract void handleInput(String input);}
```

***SimplestLevelFragment.java***

```
public class SimplestLevelFragment extends LevelModelFragment {

private final static int id = 1;
private final static String name = "The simplest level I have ever seen";
private final static String[] hints = {"Enter the name of program"};

@Override
protected View provideFragmentView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simpleLevelLayout,parent,false);
    //Now specific components here (you can initialize Buttons etc)
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean checkCompletion() {
    return this.completed;
}

@Override
public void handleInput(String input) {
    if(input == "Secret Path"){
        this.completed = true;
    }
}}
```

Maybe I should use another architecture approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you init `child Fragment` you should put common arguments into `Bundle` and call `setArguments`. In `super Fragment` inside the method `onCreate` you can get it.

```
Fragment child = new SimplestLevelFragment();
Bundle data = new Bundle();
// put common value to data
child.setArguments(data);
```

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle data = getArguments();
    // get common value you already pass
}
```